# Наследования классов от класса реализующего интерфейс

Tags: c#, ооп, .net

Есть некая абстракция. Ее описывает интерфейс. У каждой сущности есть общие черты. 
Например, есть интерфейс фигура. Все фигуры имеют общие методы (нарисовать одну точку фигуры, повернуть фигуру), но есть универсальный методы (например, увеличить радиус доступен только окружности).

Как правильно с точки зрения ООП организовать структуру программы?

Я вижу это так. Есть интерфейс, его наследует класс прародитель, который определяет общие для всех методы. Остальные фигуры наследуются от этого класса и реализуют свои методы.

Слушаю критику.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При планировании приложения *(особенно связанного с геометрическими объектами)* обычно рекомендуется досконально изучить архитектурные решения, которые были применены в других проектах.

---

**Я сгенерировал фрагмент диаграммы классов проекта [SharpMap,](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/) который коррелирует с темой вашего вопроса.**

- В этой диаграмме хорошо читаются некоторые решения, принятые во время разработки *(естественно, что во многих случаях разработчики шли на компромиссы и без изъянов не обошлось).*
- Тем не менее, `SharpMap` - разработка очень хорошего качества, поэтому тщательный анализ архитектуры этого проекта будет вам полезен.

[image]